# How to find that how many select tags are there in a div?

Tags: jquery, html

In the html I'm having a div tag. Between this `div` tag there are many other tags like `span` `select` and `p` tags shown like below:

```
<div id="show">
  <span>Span text</span>
  <span>Span text</span>
  <span>Span text</span>
  <select id="select1">
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select2">
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now how we find that how many `select tags` are in the `div` `id` having `id="show"` using jQuery.Can anyone help me to find out this.

Comment: Why do you think that he/she wants immediate child's?

Comment: I'd also consider to solve this without jQuery. With ES6 this will do the same thing
document.querySelectorAll('#show select').length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `length`:

```
$('#show select').length
```

```js
console.log($('#show select').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">
  <span>Span text</span>
  <span>Span text</span>
  <span>Span text</span>
  <select id="select1">
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select2">
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select every `select` tag that are child of `div` with id `show`.

Plus, see [jquery.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

```js
console.log($("div#show > select").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">
     <span>Span text</span>
     <span>Span text</span>
     <span>Span text</span>
     <select id="select1">
       <option>1</option>
     </select>
     <select id="select2">
       <option>1</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help full to you.

```
$('#show select').length
```